# Sentiment analysis function (not using Classify)

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking to create a function that will take a text and parameter strings "neg","pos", and "sum" and calculate a sentiment value for the text. I want to use ReplaceAll and/or "If' for this. I have two lists, one with negative (negativeWords) and one with positive words (positiveWords), and I want the function to assign the value of +1 to words in the text that are also in the positive words list, -1 to words in the text that are also in the negative words list, and 0 for words that are in neither list, and then calculate the sum of those numbers.

This is what I have so far but I am stumped :/

`ToLowerCase@TextWords@text_ /. {negativeWords -> -1, positiveWords -> 1, ! negativeWords && ! positiveWords -> 0}`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! If I understand correctly, you have your own predefined lists of positive and negative words? Can you please include a short example of these lists and a text in your question? This way, we can more easily make a good answer and test if it works as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

An `Association` together with `Lookup` and the default value `0` might do and should be reasonably efficient.

```
negativeWords = {"A", "B"};
positiveWords = {"a", "b"};

s = "A a b C, B a b A? A B b a c!";

a = Merge[{AssociationThread[positiveWords, 1], AssociationThread[negativeWords, -1]}, First]

Lookup[a, TextWords[s], 0]
```

> {-1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0}